# Cinnamon renice on launch

Tags: python, ubuntu, renice, cinnamon

I installed Ubuntu and changed shell to Cinnamon. Is there any possible way to renice on launch Cinnamon to, let's say, `-19`?

I tried to change `/usr/bin/cinnamon_launcher` like this, but it doesn't help:

```
cinnamon_pid = os.fork()
if cinnamon_pid == 0:
    os.execvp("cinnamon", ("cinnamon", "--replace", ) + tuple(sys.argv[1:]))
    Popen(["nice"], preexec_fn=lambda : os.nice(-19))
```

Thanks on your help!

Comment: I have installed Xubuntu  and solved this problem this way